# SQL/ASP connection error

Tags: asp.net, sql, connection-string

```
Line 10: 
Line 11:      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ac210db6" runat="server" 
Line 12:      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ac210db6ConnectionString %>" 
Line 13:      SelectCommand="SELECT [cid] FROM [customers]"></asp:SqlDataSource><br />
```

The connection name `ac210db6ConnectionString` was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.

Exception Details:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The connection name
>   'ac210db6ConnectionString' was not found in the applications
>   configuration or the connection string is empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check your web.config for the connection string name?

Answer (score 1):

You should have something like this in your web.config file.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ac210db6ConnectionString" connectionString="server={YOUR-SERVER-NAME-OR-IP};database={DATABASE-NAME};Integrated Security=True;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Go here for a full reference on your connection string.

http://connectionstrings.com/